# How to convert object[] to image in smart device application (C#)?

Tags: c#, casting, smartphone

I am developing smart device application in C#. In that I am calling the web services. The web service method return Google map. The return type of the method is object []. The object [] contains the image in byte format. The soap response for Google Maps image is xsi:type="xs:base64Binary". In object I am not getting the string. In object I am getting the byte array.
So I am catching the response of web service in following variable.

object [] GoogleMap;

After debugging I can see that in auto I am getting the result as follows.

Name:           Value:
GoogleMap       {object[1]}
[0]             {byte[23570]}

I need to display the actual image in my application. What type of casting I need to do to display the image.Please make sure that all the core functions of .net framework does not work with .net compact framework. Can you provide me the code or any link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Comment: Is there any reason you have not accepted any of the 16 questions you have asked?

Comment: Yeah people might stop answering your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the byte array out:

```
byte[] data = (byte[]) objects[0];
```

Then create a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) around it:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
```

Now create a `Bitmap` from the stream:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Note that you should *not* close the `MemoryStream` - when you dispose of the `Image`, that will close the stream.

(EDIT: Changed from `Image.FromStream` to calling the `Bitmap` constructor as `Image.FromStream` appears not to be in the CF.)